# How to reinstall MySQL in Cloud 9 IDE

Tags: mysql, cloud9-ide

I have a workspace in Cloud 9 IDE which was created more than 2 years ago. At that time I created simple C application to test MySQL connection. I remember application worked at that time.

Now after a long period of time I try to recompile my test application but I found that there is no mysql.h header file in the Cloud 9 virtual machine.

mysql-ctl seems to work: it reports that mysql is running. but there is no mysql headres in the filesystem.

So I think I need to reinstall MySQL in Cloud 9 but I cannot find any documentation on this topic. Also it looks like their own package manager c9pm is not supported anymore.

So how can I reinstall MySQL in Cloud 9 virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was a completely new version Cloud9 almost a year ago (https://c9.io/blog/announcing-the-all-new-cloud9-development-environment/) I can imagine something like a compilation against mysql.h got broken. I would create a new workspace and transfer your files to that workspace (use File > Download Project). In the "new" Cloud9 you can simply use `sudo apt-get install` to install software rather than use c9pm.